# How can I make Text automatically size itself?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm writing a very simple coupon application, but I'm struggling with my text. I'm re-writing my app from Kotlin to Flutter. In Kotlin I had ConstraintLayout which quickly allowed me to design interfaces. I also had there a property called autoSizeTextType="uniform" which allowed me to resize my text automatically on different screen sizes.

Have a look at my photos. On iPhone 11 Max Pro, there is a blank space between my cards and text. I'd like my text to automatically resize on different screen ratios.

[image]

However, on my Pixel 3A emulator, the text is perfectly sized.

[image]

How do I allow my text to be responsive on different screen ratio?

### Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ClassicCouponScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('DATA WYDANIA:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Text('23/12/2019', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('UNIKALNY KOD:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Text('S-58-pS-8', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Image.asset('assets/images/coupon_hamburger.png'),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
              Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                height: 95.0,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text('DRUKUJ /', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                      Text('ZAPISZ JAKO PDF', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 95.0,
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text('PRZEŚLIJ KUPON', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                      Text('(WYSYŁKA W CIĄGU 24 GODZIN)', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the [`auto_size_text` package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) in order to achieve your desired behavior.

First, you will have to [add it as a dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text#-installing-tab-) to your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
```

After installing the package, you will be able to use it inside of your layout:

```dart
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';

// ...
children: [
  // ...
  Expanded(
    child: AutoSizeText(
      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
  ),
  // ...
],
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flutter_screenutil` to make text responsive. 
Usage:

Initialize the `Screen.instance` with width px and height px of the highest screen ratio you want to support inside `build`

```
ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334)..init(context);

Text('Hello World', style: TextStyle(
   color: Colors.white,
   fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(12)),
  ),
)
```

You can also refer this blog https://medium.com/nonstopio/let-make-responsive-app-in-flutter-e48428795476

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

> Usage
>
> AutoSizeText behaves exactly like a Text. The only difference is that it resizes text to fit within its bounds.

```
AutoSizeText(
  'The text to display',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 2,
)
```